# Select XML Nodes by Attribute Value

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

I have a oracle query to generate below xml result and I like to check **only** if there is any attribute value inside  SUBQUERY and COL_LIST_ITEM nodes **not others**. If nodes has attribute value than write "it has attribute value" else "no attribute value". I am not sure if my code is correct! Is there any way to do that?

```
<VIEW xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ku" version="1.0">
    <SCHEMA value1="USER1">USER2</SCHEMA> 
    <NAME value1="VIEW_TBL_A">VIEW_TBL_B</NAME> 
    <COL_LIST> 
        <COL_LIST_ITEM> 
        </COL_LIST_ITEM> 
        <COL_LIST_ITEM src="2"> 
            <NAME>FIELD_A2</NAME> 
        </COL_LIST_ITEM> 
    </COL_LIST> 
    <SUBQUERY value1="SELECT FIELD_A1 
    FROM TBL_A 
    WHERE FIELD_A1 = 111">SELECT FIELD_A1, FIELD_A2 
    FROM TBL_A 
    WHERE FIELD_A1 = 111</SUBQUERY> 
</VIEW>
```

**Here is my Code**

```
using (OracleConnection conn1 = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
{
    conn1.Open();
    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT dbms_metadata.get_sxml('VIEW','VIEW_TBL_A') FROM dual;", conn1))
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am not sure if my code is correct!` It can't be wrong while doing nothing related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about an XDocument

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
XNamespace ns = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/ku";

if (doc.Descendants(ns + "COL_LIST_ITEM").Any(c => c.Attributes().Any()))
    Console.WriteLine("COL_LIST has value");
```

and of course add your other nodes in to check

Comment: "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: Add a reference to System.Xml.Linq

Comment: I already add System.Xml.Linq reference, but still shows the error!

Comment: did you add `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: code gives ORA-00911: invalid character at  XDocument doc= Document.Load(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());*   Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should use LINQ to XML to query your XML document:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
    from element in document.Root.Elements("SUBQUERY")
    where element.HasAttributes
    select element;
```

Refer to the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.  'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Comment: Where can I add If statement nodes has attribute value than write "it has attribute value" else "no attribute value

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar problem, while working on a Universal Windows App, and was also very frustrated when VS didn't specify clearly what the problem was. Although after hours of surfing the web, I found the solution. It was simple, but i don't know why VS didn't specify it. Anyways, here it is :-

Add another reference to your project :- 
**using System.Linq;** *apart from* **using System.Xml.Linq;**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

The errors will go & the project will build.

---

For more help reference this article :-

[problem with using refrence to System.Xml.Linq](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/23a2e0b1-63e5-4aa7-ba46-0fca173bf348/query-xdocument-using-linq)